# Different method called when using Laravel form request validation

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a controller (`API\Fields`) with a method named `store`, the route to that method is set up like this:

`POST /api/templates/{template}/fields -> API\Fields@store`

Everything worked properly until I created a very simple form request validation class with the following rules *(This is the only thing I changed besides the return value for the `authorize` method)*:

```
    return [
        'name'          =>  ['required', 'alpha_num'],
        'coordinates'   =>  ['required', 'json'],
        'type'          =>  ['required', BaseField::RULE],
        'page'          =>  ['required', 'numeric'],
        'readonly'      =>  ['sometimes', 'boolean'],
        'required'      =>  ['sometimes', 'boolean']
    ];
```

After I created the class, I simply changed the request class from `Request`, to `CreateFieldsRequest` and it messed pretty much the whole routing for that route up. Instead of calling `store`, Laravel seems to be calling `index`. When I restore `CreateFieldsRequest` back to just the `Request` class, it behaves as it should again.

I haven't been able to find any information on this topic, and I've verified over and over that I don't have some sort of incorrect routing or redirections on any of the related classes.

Any help or guidance with this would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run the request through the Chrome developer console as a POST request, Laravel kicks it back as a "GET" request, not sure why.

A `FormRequest` that fails validation [issues a redirect](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L128). It's the default behavior.

If you issue an AJAX request, or request a JSON response with an `Accept` header, it'll [respond with a JSON list of validation errors and a 422 HTTP code instead](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/262b813fc88810071f8282722a89eb5199cb398a/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L129).

Comment: Thank you! I found an issue about this on the repo once I figured out that it was a redirect that was giving the issue. Adding a `X-Requested-With` header has also fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

After running a very simple test I realized that this seems to be an issue with **Postman**. If you are experiencing this issue stick to adding a `_method=POST` parameter on your POST body, or simply use XHR or a different API testing tool.

**Edit: After further testing I realized the issue had not been fixed. When I run the request through the Chrome developer console as a POST request, Laravel kicks it back as a "GET" request, not sure why.**

Comment: This is only necessary if you're not sending the request as an actual POST. Postman can absolutely do it, but it sounds like you're sending some other type of request (a GET, most likely).

Comment: Yeah, I realized that the issue had not been fixed. However I noticed that when I send the request as a POST request via the Chrome developer console, Laravel kicks it back and then Chrome shows it as a GET request. Once I change the request type back to `Request`, it shows a POST request type as it should.

Comment: That sounds like you're receiving a redirect due to failed validation, which is [the default behavior for a FormRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e6c8aa0e39d8f91068ad1c299546536e9f25ef63/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L128).